# Apply two different Sklearn classifiers to two different subsets of the same data

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, pipelines

I have a dataset that I need to run through a classification Pipeline. The dataset has 2 types of rows:

- **described:** `description` column POPULATED
- **non-described:** `description` column EMPTY

I want to apply one classifier targetting ONLY the described data, and another one for the non-described data.

I am currently doing so by separating the dataset, and then preprocessing and feeding the dataset to their corresponding classifier separately. What I want to accomplish is fitting this process into a Sklearn pipeline. It should be something like this:

```
classifierPipe = Pipeline([('preproc_described', DescPreprocessor),
                           ('preproc_non_described', NonDescPreprocessor),
                           ('clf_described', CLF1),
                           ('clf_non_described', CLF2)
                          ])

classifierPipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I was reviewing `StackingClassifier`, but according to the documentation, initial estimators are applied to all the rows in the dataset.

How can I create such a pipeline where each classifier targets a specific subset of the whole dataset?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I want to split the dataset in 2 different subsets, say, `SUBSET1` and `SUBSET2`, and run a different classifier on each one. BUT I want to run it in a single pipe fit/predict routine. I want to know if I can call `classifierPipe.fit(X,y)`, and have `CLF1` trained with one SUBSET1 and CLF2 trained with `SUBSET2`. then by calling `classifierPipe.predict(X,y)`, `CLF1` would only predict on `SUBSET1` and `CLF2` would only predict on `SUBSET2`